# Java - How do I get Pass percentage in Extent Report 3.X

Tags: selenium-extent-report, extentreports

I have been using Extend report for generating my Test results. All these days I used to use 2.41 version. Now, I have been using 3.0.7 version.

**Issue:**

2.41 used to display **Pass percentage** in Dashboard.

How do i get Pass percentage in Dashboard for 3.0.7 version.

Comment: If you put your mouse over pass count under chart I believe you should see it.

Comment: Yeah I know this, however I don't want each and everytime to hover on it and check for Pass percentage. Is there any other way where we can show Pass percentage??